# Unable to create an authentication session on Codemagic when code signing on ios

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I feel like I'm missing something but can't be sure really. I'm trying to use automatic code signing feature of codemagic for IOS app store release.

But during build it prints;

```
> /usr/local/bin/flutter build ios --release --no-codesign

Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
```

And during publish it prints;

```
"Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-22020 \"We are unable to create an authentication session.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=We are unable to create an authentication session., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}"
```

I'm enabling app store connect, choosing automatic code signing and choosing app store for provisioning profile type. And I'm sure my ID and other fields are correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the `--no-codesign` part. Codemagic firsts build the app without signing it and then signs the app. Your problem seems more related to the connection with your apple account. Did you properly set App Store Connect with an App Specific Password instead of your usual password ?

Comment: Is app specific password different than usual? If so where can I find it please?

Comment: Yes it's a different one. You can create it  by going to your apple id (https://appleid.apple.com/), down to Security, and then App Specific Password / Generate a password

Comment: Ah, you were right found it and fixed thanks mate just add your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about the `--no-codesign` part. Codemagic firsts build the app without signing it and then signs the app.

Your problem seems more related to the connection with your apple account. You have to set **App Store Connect** with an App Specific Password instead of your usual password.

To do so, go to your [apple id](https://appleid.apple.com) page, down to *Security*, and then *App Specific Password* > *Generate a password*

Comment: Thanks once again! :)